# AngularJS controller instantiation in unit tests - functions not binding to scope values

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a service that **synchronously** returns data to a controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller(function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.foo = myService.getFoo();
});
```

This works just fine *in the browser*.  In my unit tests, `$scope.foo` is undefined:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  module('app');
  myService = jasmine.createSpyObj('myService', ['getFoo']);

  inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('ModelSliderCtrl', {
      myService: myService,
      $scope: $scope
    });
  });
});

it('should have foo on the scope', function() {
  myService.getFoo.and.returnValue({});

  expect(myService.getFoo).toHaveBeenCalled();  // PASS
  $scope.$digest();
  expect($scope.foo).toBeDefined();  // FAIL - $scope.foo is undefined
});
```

This *does* work in both the browser and tests:

```
angular.module('app').controller(function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.foo = myService.getFoo();
  };

  $scope.init();
});
```

.

```
it('should have foo on the scope', function() {
  myService.getFoo.and.returnValue({});

  $scope.init();
  expect(myService.getFoo).toHaveBeenCalled();  // PASS
  expect($scope.foo).toBeDefined();  // PASS
});
```

I'd like to believe I'm fairly well-versed in Angular, Jasmine and JavaScript.  I've also asked some colleagues who are equally puzzled.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: What is the type of foo? is it a promise?

Comment: No, you can see it's being mocked to return a plain object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting up a mock

```
it('should have foo on the scope', function() {
  myService.getFoo.and.returnValue({});
```

after your controller has been instantiated.  It's too late to set up the mock by then, do it before instantiating your controller since you are executing `init()` right away.

```
  myService = jasmine.createSpyObj('myService', ['getFoo']);
  myService.getFoo.and.returnValue({});

  inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
```